# Is it possible to make this JSON object? How can I?

Tags: javascript, json

How can I make a json array like this? Is it possible?

```
"data" : [
        "1000": "1000",
        "1200": "1200",
        "1400": "1400",
        "1600": "1600",
        "1800": "1800",
]
```

or

```
"data" : [
        1000: 1000,
        1200: 1200,
        1400: 1400,
        1600: 1600,
        1800: 1800,
]
```

Not like this

```
"data" : [
 "1000",
 "1200",
 "1400",
 "1600",
 "1800",
]
```

or

```
"data" : [
        0: "1000",
        1: "1200",
        2: "1400",
        3: "1600",
        4: "1800",
]
```

Note: String or integer, that does not a matter.

I only want to use an integer. Not any letters or words.

Comment: The only possible syntax is the second. Why insist on an array and not use an object?

Comment: Note that your wished format is not valid for JSON. You have to use {} instead of [] to make it at least valid JSON. Please read through [this info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using JSON or a JavaScript [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) instead of an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), like this:

```
"data" : {
        "1000": "1000",
        "1200": "1200",
        "1400": "1400",
        "1600": "1600",
        "1800": "1800",
}
```

Note that the square brackets have been replaced with curly brackets. This signifies a JavaScript object, where each "key" has a "value" - for instance, the first key-value pair is `"1000"` and `"1000"`. If you want to assign this object to a JavaScript variable, you can do so like this:

```
var data = {
        "1000": "1000",
        "1200": "1200",
        "1400": "1400",
        "1600": "1600",
        "1800": "1800",
}
```

To access these values, you can use `data["1000"]` to access the property `"1000"` - this will return the value `"1000"`. You could use numbers as the values instead of strings, like this:

```
"data" : {
        "1000": 1000,
        "1200": 1200,
        "1400": 1400,
        "1600": 1600,
        "1800": 1800,
}
```

Otherwise, you can convert the string values into numeric ones using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

`parseInt(data["1000"]);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

```
var data = [
        "1000": "1000",
        "1200": "1200",
        "1400": "1400",
        "1600": "1600",
        "1800": "1800",
]

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: This is syntactic nonsense.